# 1D Motion: Average Velocity without Direction?

Tags: velocity

How come this solution doesn't include direction for average velocity since it is a vector?

> Calculate the average velocity at a particular time interval of a particle if it is moves 5 m at 2 s and 15 m at 4s along x-axis?

[image]

Shouldn't average velocity (a vector) be denoted $\vec{V_{av}}$ and it should equal $5\hat{i}$ m/s?

**Edit 1:**

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  I have typed out the question which is sufficient for search indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so, as this particular problem has already somewhat defined the setting that they take velocities along the line of the x-axis hence the solution is consistent with the system taken here and vectors aren’t needed to complicate the result. Indeed using $5i$ would be just as accurate **if** the question had defined a unit vector along the x-axis as $i$.

Physicists and mathematicians often want to simplify problems if they can afford it without bringing much inaccuracies as it is done here. As here notice that there is no motion along the *y-axis*. Hence there is really no need for a **two-dimensional** analysis. This is often done to simplify problems without being unnecessary redundancies which would just mean extra writing. However if the problem did indeed have both x and y movements then it would indeed be very useful to use $i$ and $j$ after defining them.

Comment: Okay, but what about the missing arrow for vectors?

Comment: Maybe here they consider the *magnitude* of the velocity which is indeed a scalar and needs no arrow.

Comment: But if they do mean average velocity, which is a vector, it must be denoted with an arrow above it, no exceptions?

Comment: Yes indeed, notation is a matter of convention. You can use an arrow, a bold or even an underline to represent a vector. But often when a vector is one-dimensional(like here), it’s alright to write it without an arrow as you can’t really confuse it with a scalar here as everything is positive and one-dimensional.

Comment: It would **not** be alright when it’s 2-D as that would lead to confusions whether you are indicating a scalar or a vector but in one dimension with a solely positive direction, notice that the magnitude of the velocity is the velocity itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone, after much searching, I found an excerpt from the textbook which I think agrees with what you guys are saying. See **Edit 1**

Answer (score 0):

> if it is at 5 m at 2 s and 15 m at 4s along $x$-axis

The "along the $x$-axis" already took care of the direction. All that's left is to analyse the magnitude.